# Webpart visible when editting, but disappears

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

We cannot figure out what is going on with Sharepoint here. We edit the page and add webparts fine, however, when saved and published a few of those webparts disappear.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how to fix this? Seen anything like this before?

Not visible when published

[image: Call to Action webpart is not visible when saved and published.]

Editing makesit visible...
[image: Call to Action webpart is visible when editting]

What is happening when we publish to make it disappear?

Comment: After more investigation we think it has something to do with collapsible sections but I can't find documentation to support that.